# Как совместить flask и phpmyadmin на apache?

Tags: python, phpmyadmin, flask, url, apache2

Добрый вечер у меня есть приложение на flask на хостинге apache2. И когда я его запускаю он заберает все ссылки после домена. у меня вопрос. Как зделать что бы после запроса на мой_домен.com/phpmyadmin он показывал именно phpMyAdmin а не что либо другое.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Создайте в apache подомен типа pma.мой_домен.com и подключите phpmyadmin через него